# Dry-validation how to allow array of hashes with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry-validation

This is how I'm trying to allow a `nil` value for an array of hashes (Im using [dry-validations gem](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-validation))

```rb
required(:properties).maybe(:array).each(:hash)
```

This is raising the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/svelandiag/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dry-logic-1.2.0/lib/dry/logic/operations/each.rb:15:in `call'
```

How to allow a `nil` value in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it actually took me a bit of time, but the answer seems to be here https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-schema/1.9/basics/macros/#maybe

You cannot use `maybe` with `each`, you should do this instead:

```rb
required(:properties).maybe(:array) do
  nil? | each(:hash)
end
```

It took me a decent amount of time to find the answer since I was looking at the "Nested Data" section within dry-schema docs, I would suggest that if some contributor of the project is seeing this, please add a similar section to explain that `maybe` and `each` are not compatible in the "Nested Data" section of the dry-schema docs https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-schema/1.9/nested-data/

Comment: The doc sources  are part of the [dry-schema repository on GitHub](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-schema/blob/main/docsite/source/nested-data.html.md). I'm sure the maintainers would appreciate a pull request to improve the documentation.

Comment: Seems like `maybe(array[:hash])` would also work. It should expand into `!nil?.then(array? & each(hash?))`. Since `maybe` can be `nil?` it seesm to make sense that it would not work well with `each` (as you are seeing in your error)